# Query is not working if I add more database column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update multiple row in my `query` but it's not working. But if I try to update only one `row`, it's working

Here is my working code:

```
        if(!empty($_POST['include'])) {
            foreach($_POST['include'] as $check) {
                echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"master[]\" size=\"50\" value=\"$check\"> <br/>";

            $vessel = 'SAMMY';
                $query = "UPDATE `info` SET `vessel` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $vessel, $check);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            }
        }
```

Here is my not working code:

```
        if(!empty($_POST['include'])) {
            foreach($_POST['include'] as $check) {
                echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"master[]\" size=\"50\" value=\"$check\"> <br/>";

                $crew_status = 'LINEUP PENDING';
            $vessel = 'SAMMY';
                $query = "UPDATE `info` SET `vessel` = ? AND `crew_status` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssi', $vessel, $crew_status, $check);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What means `not working`? Any error message?

Comment: no error but the query is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `AND` in your SQL query, use a `,` instead:

```
UPDATE `info` SET `vessel` = ?, `crew_status` = ? WHERE `id` = ?"
```

When setting multiple values with an `Update` query in MySQL, you must seperate them with a comma according to the MySQL documentation about [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

Comment: this one worked. can you tell me what is the difference?

Comment: @aronpascua I have updated my answer. It is merely the syntax of the update statement - multiple columns should be seperated by comma